# FLTK - Mac iOS image not displayed

Tags: c++, image, macos, makefile, fltk

I am using FLTK library (version 1.3.5) on iOS Mojave 10.14.6: I wrote this simple program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/platform.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_JPEG_Image.H>
#include <FL/Fl_PNG_Image.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Fl_Window *G_win = 0;
    G_win = new Fl_Window(650,650,"test");

    Fl_Box* BG = new Fl_Box(0,0,650,650);
    Fl_PNG_Image *bg = new Fl_PNG_Image("scheme.png");
    BG->image(bg);

    Fl_Box* text = new Fl_Box(250,20,150,20,"There should be an image down below. Is it so?");

    G_win->end();
    G_win->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

and I compile it with the following Makefile (found [here](https://www.fltk.org/articles.php?L599)):

```
CC  = $(shell fltk-config --cc)
CXX = $(shell fltk-config --cxx)

CFLAGS   = $(shell fltk-config --cflags) -Wall -O3 -I/other/include/paths...
CXXFLAGS = $(shell fltk-config --cxxflags) -Wall -O3 -I/other/include/paths...

LINKFLTK = $(shell fltk-config --ldstaticflags)
LINKFLTK_GL = $(shell fltk-config --use-gl --ldstaticflags)
LINKFLTK_IMG = $(shell fltk-config --use-images --ldstaticflags)

STRIP      = strip
POSTBUILD  = fltk-config --post # Required on OSX, does nothing on other platforms, so safe to call

all: myApp

main.o: main.cpp 
    $(CC) -c $< $(CCFLAGS)

myApp:  main.o 
    $(CXX) -o $@ main.o  $(LINKFLTK_IMG) $(LINKFLTK_GL)
    $(STRIP) $@
    $(POSTBUILD) $@  # only required on OSX, but call it anyway for portability
```

I get hence the binary `myApp` and the application `myApp`: when I type ./myApp in the shell eveything works fine (top image), while by double-clicking on the icon there is no image displayed (bottom image).

[image: Executing the binary] [image: double clicking on the app]

I got no errors during compilation, nor warnings. Are there any problems with the Makefile? Is it Mac iOS related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is so simply because FLTK is trying to load the PNG file from the *current* folder. When you execute `./myApp` in the shell, it is running in the same folder where the PNG file is located. When you double-click however, your curent path is who-knows-where.

The simplest "fix" is to use an absolute path (something like "/home/youruser/work/myapp/scheme.png"), recompile the application, and run it. - It should work if you supplied the full path to the file.

Comment: Perfect, you were right, it worked like a charm! I thought that since they are in the same directory the .app should have find the png file. I would like to avoid giving absolute paths, so I'll search some way to include the images in the ".app bundle". I will try what it is suggested here: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#MacBundle

Comment: Yep. That is why I wrote it was the "simplest" fix. Much better would be to write a tiny loader for an example, or similar.